# change values in column if duplicate and corresponding meets criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where there are duplicates in first column. In the third column there is another label but, these have duplicated data. I want to change all the duplicated data, if not matching to 'covered' if there is a duplicate in initial column and 'covered'apparent.

Picture below: SAWAD should both be changed to covered. SC should remain not covered. SCB should all change to covered

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is test if at least one `Covered` per group by compre by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html) :

```
m = df['Covered/Not Covered'].eq('Covered').groupby(df['Security']).transform('any')
```

Or get all `Security` values with `Covered` and test column by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for all groups:

```
m = df['Security'].isin(df.loc[df['Covered/Not Covered'].eq('Covered'), 'Security'])
```

And then set original values by mask:

```
df.loc[m, 'Covered/Not Covered'] = 'Covered'
```